# How to display pdf files from database in Google Docs?

Tags: php, pdf, google-docs

Here is my code.

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url<?php echo $file_row['floc']; ?>"> <i class="text-warning">View </i></a>
```

It echos the file`.pdf` in the database, when I clicked the link I want to redirect in `Google docs`. the google docs said they cannot find the specified folder.

Can someone help me to view the files into `Google Docs` after i clicked the link?

Comment: You should rethink this question and try again. Also, your code didn't post.

Comment: sorry, the is here

<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url<?php echo $file_row['floc']; ?>"> <i class="text-warning">View </i></a>

Answer (score 0):

Try **[rawurlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)** and do not forget about `=` here `?url=`:

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php echo rawurlencode($file_row['floc']); ?>">
```

But your `$file_row['floc']` does not contain an URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/uploads/4145_File_app-developer-guide-2.4.pdf
```

a path only:

```
uploads/4145_File_app-developer-guide-2.4.pdf
```

Try add a schema and a domain:

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://domain.com/<?php echo rawurlencode($file_row['floc']); ?
```

Comment: thank you for the anaswer, but it didn't work for me. google docs unable to find the document at the original source. is there any way I can view pdf files using the link from the database?

Comment: @AlvinMarcLagundino Show a value of `$file_row['floc']`

Comment: I think my code is lacking something, because it only displays the url of the pdf file in the server, example is --->https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=uploads/4145_File_app-developer-guide-2.4.pdf

-- my code is getting only the path which my pdf folder is uploaded not the complete url

Comment: here is the query

<?php
                            $file_query = mysql_query("select * from files  ORDER BY fdatein DESC") or die(mysql_error());
                            while ($file_row = mysql_fetch_array($file_query)) {
                                $file_id = $file_row['file_id'];
                                ?>

----> the floc is the the column of the .pdf file in my database

Comment: how would I display the pdf files using only the path? sorry I am only a beginner in php.

Comment: Google viewer downloads a file. So it must be somewhere and google takes it by URL, not by path.

Comment: I still running it in the localhost  how can I modify the url? 

http://localhost/dameans-bb/cet_page.php -the url before I clicked the link