# re- How to display pdf files from database in Google Docs?

Tags: php, google-docs

I want to display my pdf file in google docs using the link. 
the 'floc' is the file name in my database which contains the .pdf files.

here is my code--->

```
                        <td><?php echo $file_row['fname']; ?> </td>
                        <td><a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php echo urldecode($file_row['floc']); ?>"> <i class="text-warning">View </i></a></td>

                        <td><em><i class="text-success"><?php echo $file_row['fdatein']; ?></i></em></td>
```

Thanks for the immediate help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display pdf files from database in Google Docs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669619/how-to-display-pdf-files-from-database-in-google-docs)

Comment: please don't ask your questions twice

Answer (score 0):

try putting it in an iframe e.g.

```
 <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://yourpdf&embedded=true#:0.page.1">
```

Comment: tip - combine your pdf files into one document using adobe readers 'create file from multiple files' feature - it might make your life easier

Comment: the code is not for url, it is only a path which my .pdf files is stored. what I want is to display the pdf files using the link that echoes the .pdf file from my database table

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I am still learning and I have known only the basics in php